# Probability - how to satisfy an order with given probability?

Tags: probability

The probability that randomly chosen shirt from a current production can be qualified as a premium sort shirt is $p = 0.8$.  Find the probability that out of $n = 100$ shirts we will have at least $85$ premium sort shirts.  How many shirts we have to produce to satisfy an order for $400$ premium sort shirts with probability at least $0.99$?

[edit]

First part of the question :
$$p = 0.8   \\
n = 100  \\
E(X) = p\,n = 80.  \\
 V(X) = p\,n\,(1-p) = 16 \\
P(X\geq 85)= 1 - P(X\leq 84) = 1 - 0.8708 = 0.1292 
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem and can share them so responders can provide better guidance? Regards

Comment: I have a problem with the second part of this problem. First one should be like: 
p = 0.8  n = 100 
E(X) = p*n = 80. 
V(X) = P*N*(1-p) = 16 

P(X>=85)= 1 - P(X=<84) = 1 - 0.8708 = 0.1292

Comment: Where did you get the number $0.8708$?  Are you using the normal-distribution approximation?

Comment: yes, and i get this value from the tables; phi(1.13)

Comment: Ah, that works.  Your work for the first part seems fine.  I'll post something for the second part shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the second part is different from the first part in that instead of computing a probability, we begin with a probability and proceed backwards.  First of all, we need to find a number $z$ so that $\text{phi}(z)=(1-0.99)=0.01$. You should get $z=-2.33$, or something close.

Now, let $n$ be the number of shirts that will be "enough" under the constraints of the second problem. We know that $n$ has to satisfy
$$
n p + z\sqrt{np(1-p)}\geq 400
$$
Changing this to an equality, we rearrange this to get
$$
z\sqrt{np(1-p)}= 400 - n p\\
z^2np(1-p)= 160000-800np + n^2 p^2\\
(p^2)n^2-((800+z^2(1-p))p)n + 160000=0
$$
This is a quadratic equation you can solve for $n$.  Round the answer up to get your solution.

Comment: Let me know if there's any way I can make this clearer

Comment: I had a typo in the last line; I've changed a "$-$" in the last equation to a "$+$".  Glad to help (:.